# LINQ - convert group to array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have a problem displaying most popular tags from database in view. I'm not sure about this question title so if someone has a better one please do rename it.

### Scenario

I need to show recent posts, recent galleries and most popular tags on my index page. I decided to use tuples for this and it worked fine until I tried to show most popular tags.

### Error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Tuple`3[photoBlog.Models.Gallery[],photoBlog.Models.Post[],System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,photoBlog.Models.PostTag][]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Tuple`3[photoBlog.Models.Gallery[],photoBlog.Models.Post[],photoBlog.Models.PostTag[]]'.

As you can see it gives my view wrong object type. I want expect it to be an array, but it gives me some kind of `System.Linq.Grouping` item.

### Code

As you can see I convert it into array in my controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    photoBlogModelDataContext _db = new photoBlogModelDataContext();
    var posts = _db.Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).Take(4).ToArray();
    var galleries = _db.Galleries.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(4).ToArray();
    var posttags = _db.PostTags.GroupBy(x => x.TagID).OrderBy(x => x.Count()).Take(4).ToArray();
    return View(Tuple.Create(galleries, posts, posttags));
}
```

My view is straight forward, note that this did work until I tried to add most popular tags.

```
@model Tuple<photoBlog.Models.Gallery[], photoBlog.Models.Post[], photoBlog.Models.PostTag[]>
@foreach (var tag in Model.Item3)
{ 
    @tag.Tag.Name
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want

```
var posttags = _db.PostTags
    .GroupBy(x => x.TagID)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Count())
    // Take each group and pass the first tag of the group
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .Take(4)
    .ToArray();
```

At the moment you're passing e.g. all 8 instances of the most popular tag, all 5 instances of the second most popular, etc., each in their own group. I imagine you just want to pass an "example" of each tag.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to completely dodge the casting issue, but how about simplifying a little:

```
public class PopularStatsViewModel{
  public Gallery[] Galleries { get; set; }
  public Post[] Posts { get; set; }
  public PostTags[] Tags { get; set; }
}
```

New up a PopularStats instance and set the properties to the results of your db calls.  Then in your view:

```
@model photoblog.Models.PopularStatsViewModel
```

This gets you past the casting problem, sure, but more importantly it makes it a little easier to test, gives you a little more freedom in refactoring/extending that stats object, and it's pretty clear what you're working with on the view when you're accessing the VM properties.

Comment: List would be even better for what he needs.This is a solution I suggested in another post made by him; he chose not to follow it;now I root for him to finnish it the hard way ^ ^

Comment: Lol...Agreed...I would favor List as well.

Comment: @Noobsyke Hehe, I will most certainly implement this solution later. However at the moment I am on very tight schedule and have no time for testing new things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `photoBlog.Models.PostTag[]` to `IGrouping<TagIDType, photoBlog.Models.PostTag>[]`